# unable to use watch with kubectl and xargs

Tags: bash, shell, watch, xargs

Team, I am trying to run the below every 5seconds but no luck.

```
watch -n 5 kubectl get pods -n testes-asdf-234-asdf | grep -v Comple | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl logs $1 -n testes-asdf-234-asdf main --tail=15' --
```

output:

```
does nothing
```

tried using quotes and command execution is messed up not yielding right output. my command works perfectly when used without watch and quotes

```
watch "kubectl get pods --no-headers -n testes-asdf-234-asdf | grep -v Comple | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl logs $1 -n testes-asdf-234-asdf main --tail=15' --"
```

```
Every 2.0s: kubectl get pods --no-headers -n testes-asdf-234-asdf | grep -v Comple | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl logs  -n testes...  Wed Dec  4 10:10:18 2019

Error from server (NotFound): pods "main" not found
Error from server (NotFound): pods "main" not found
Error from server (NotFound): pods "main" not found
Error from server (NotFound): pods "main" not found
Error from server (NotFound): pods "main" not found
```

Without WATCH runs fine

```
└─ $ ▶ kubectl get pods --no-headers -n testes-asdf-234-asdf | grep -v Comple | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl logs $1 -n testes-asdf-234-asdf main --tail=15' --

**** Stack trace ****
/roadrunner/roadrunner: dw::core::Exception::Exception(dwStatus, char const*)+0xa1 [0xcdfc31]
/roadrunner/roadrunner: dw::roadcast::RoadCastServerEngine::checkMessageEnabledStatus(dwRoadCastMessageType, char const*)+0x3a [0x1c0e1ea]
/roadrunner/roadrunner() [0x1bc2f2a]
/roadrunner/roadrunner: dwRoadCastServer_sendImage()+0x72 [0x1bc4302]
/roadrunner/roadrunner: roadrunner::castData(dwImageObject*, char const*, long, long, unsigned long)+0x66 [0xd03726]
/roadrunner/roadrunner: roadrunner::RRMainPipeline::getCameraEventFrames(roadrunner::CameraFrame**, unsigned int&, roadrunner::RRMainPipeline::CameraFrameList&, dwSensorEvent const*)+0x75c [0xb2c91c]
/roadrunner/roadrunner: roadrunner::RRMainPipeline::getCameraFrames(roadrunner::RRMainPipeline::CameraFrameList*&, roadrunner::CameraFrame**, unsigned int&)+0x3b9 [0xb31039]
/roadrunner/roadrunner: roadrunner::RRMainPipeline::cameraThreadLoop()+0x634 [0xb44b64]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: ()+0xbd8f0 [0x7f8fe0a6f8f0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: ()+0x76ba [0x7f90050eb6ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: clone()+0x6d [0x7f8fdff9e41d]
```

Comment: You can try `xargs -I{} sh -c 'kubectl logs {} -n `etc instead of doing the `$1` expansion.  The `$1` inside single quotes seems problematic

Comment: can you please post adjustment along with mine. am getting lot of syntax errors trying your solution. like post my whole command with suggested edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you put your command in quotes, bash will try to pass the output of `watch ... kubectl ...` to the first `grep`, but `watch` will never exit.

So try this:

```
watch -n 5 "kubectl get pods -n test | grep -v Comple | xargs -l1 -- sh -c 'kubectl logs \$1 -n test main --tail=15' --"
```

EDIT:
Didn't notice you had a `$1` in there. You need to escape the `$`, as it's now enclosed in double quotes and it will just be expanded to an empty string (as per the output you've shown).

I edited the command above to reflect that.

Comment: I tried but it messes the output. am adding it in question above

Comment: yeah, after that only i posted quested. also added that to question with output.

Comment: Got it. I think all you need to do is put a \ in front of `$`, as otherwise `$1` will be expanded to an empty string when evaluating that string (edited my answer).